# Display single coefficient plots in quantile regressions?

Tags: r, plot, knitr, quantreg

I am plotting regression summaries for a quantile regression I did with `quantreg`.
Obviously the method `plot.summary.rqs` is in use here. The problem is that is use quite a few explanatory variables each of which are displayed in the plot. Most of the coefficients behave not significantly different from OLS, so I just want to pick out and display a few of them.

How can I select the plots that I need to show? I am using `knitr` for my reports but do not want to show dozens of variables (and you get there quickly using dummies). Is there a way to cherry pick?

Answer (score 1):

By default, `plot.summary.rqs` plots all coefficients:

```
library(quantreg)
data(stackloss)

myrq <- rq(stack.loss ~ Air.Flow + Water.Temp + Acid.Conc., tau = seq(0.35, 0.65, 0.1), data=stackloss)
plot(summary(myrq)) # Plots all 4 coefficients
```

To cherry pick coefficients, the `parm` argument can be used:

```
plot(summary(myrq), parm = 2) # Plot only second regressor (Air.Flow)
plot(summary(myrq), parm = "Water.Temp") # Plot only Water.Temp
plot(summary(myrq), parm = 3:4) # Plot third and fourth regressor
```